# Getting links from xml file in Jmeter to make http requests

Tags: http, request, jmeter

I have an xml file which includes the links of different websites. I will need to make HTTP requests in Jmeter to these sites and there are tons of web sites so I cannot do this job by simply typing with hand. How can I read links from xml file and put those link to test in Jmeter?

Comment: from where you want to get the xml , is it located in other website or on your server ? also do you have the jmeter server setup on remote server or on your own machine ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter read XML file]
2. Add [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) as a child of the HTTP Request and configure it to read the links from the XML file using [XPath query](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).
3. Add [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to your Test Plan and configure it to match the variable you define in the XPath Extractor
4. Add HTTP Request sampler as a child of the ForEach Controller and configure it to use output variable of the ForEach Controller

Overall Test Plan structure would be something like:

[image: JMeter XPath ForEach]

Comment: I am stuck at how to use variables between elements